# What's wrong with the Weather widget on OS X 10.10 Yosemite?

Tags: macos

I have a little problem with the Weather widget in Notification Center in Yosemite. It appears to be missing some of the info from the server.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Where is the app from (I can't see it on my Yosemite machine)

Comment: It's native in notifications, like on iOS.

Comment: What info do you think is missing

Comment: Just update the screenshot above with question signs. Percentage is nonsense, but the missing weather symbol on Friday - is strange, because in Weather Channel site it's normal.

Comment: On my notifications all fields are filled in (except the one above sunset I think) - does this always happen and is it the same fields?

Comment: Answer to your question: I add new screenshot above: on the left side the situation today, on the right - after few minutes. All is very strange. Also trying to turn off the geolocation and add town by myself - didn't help, change town to another - the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With 10.10.2 update this problem fixed.